# Is there any way to create blank spaces to be filled up in MS-Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Please see the attached image. [image]

I would like to create a paragraph that will have a blank space like in the **8. Occupancy** parapgraph of the attached image.

There are two blank spaces (with underline style) in between words. Suppose I will compose this page and will give to other users and they will fill up the blank spaces. Although here "3" are written by hands, but I want those two 3 will be typed by the keyboard on the pc.

Here the most interesting thing I want. Typing "3" on the blank spaces will not move or change the width of the "underlined" area. I can accomplish this by creating Tabs with ..... leader but that is not possible if there are multiple blank spaces in different lines of a same paragraph. So, let's say the "underlined" area is 2 cm width, typing "3" over the underline will keep it as 2 cm unless the typed words are smaller than 2cm. Make sense?

Please let me know whether there is a way to accomplish that in an easy way in MS-Word?

Thanks

Comment: I'd approach this as a PDF for 2 reasons, 1. It can do that easily & 2. You really don't want this type of document to actually be editable by any 3rd party.

Comment: Look into "forms" either PDF or Word; these end up be "templates" which when used to create a document act as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a Character style that is based on the Paragraph of where it is being used. Add a Font format of Underline.

[image]

Use a Listbox Content Control and set it so that it uses your unique underline character style. Based on your specification that the entry areas need to stay of fixed length, underlined, and the user will type in the number versus handwrite it, you will have to build the Listbox selections already formatted. Here’s an example:

[image]

You will need to include a text prompt as the first line of the list that is the same length as the actual number choices below them. It will take some experimenting to get them the same length ... my example still isn’t quite perfect.

Note in my example that I had to include some underline characters before and after the numbers. This is to preserve the length of the entry field so the body next to this entry field does not shift.

When the user selects from this control, their choices look like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### In Word, you can use either a Content Control or a MacroButton Prompt Field.

Here is my writing on the [MacroButton Field Prompt](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#MacroButtonField). It's biggest advantage is that it works in pre-ribbon versions of Word. Despite the name, no macros are involved in using this method. Here is a link to my [free Add-In](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#MacroButtonPrompt) to easily insert these. You do not need the Add-In, though.

Content Controls are found under the Developer Tab in Word. Here is a [page by Greg Maxey](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html) on Content Controls.